# Searching photos by metadata with Adobe Bridge not returning results?

Tags: metadata, search, adobe-bridge

I have a photo library tagged (IPTC) with titles and descriptions in the metadata.

When I search in Adobe Bridge it only returns a few of the results. I'm using the proper search too, not the quick search, and metadata is included.

Any way to get Bridge to recognize the photos? Does it have to build an index or something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by restarting Adobe Bridge and then clicking the little pen icon next to the metadata IPTC core info, and also waiting for the messages on the bottom left "Rebuilding index".

Also I had to use the menu find, not the quick search, and select "metadata" and check the box "include non-indexed files"

Wow, they really make it hard.